# Mule ESB: Filter based on HTTP method

Tags: mule

I'm wondering if there is a way to filter / route messages based on HTTP method. What I'm looking to do is NOT process incoming requests that have been posted with the OPTIONS method. (this is for cross-origin resource share handling)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use MEL(Mule Exression Language - http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL) to query the http.method param and a choice router if you want to do something with OPTIONS request such as send back the allowed methods like so:

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.method'] == 'OPTIONS']">
        <http:response-builder status="200"
            doc:name="HTTP Response Builder(200 - OPTIONS)">
            <http:header name="Allow" value="GET" />
            <http:header name="Content-Type" value="#[null]" />
            <set-payload value="#[null]" />
        </http:response-builder>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <!-- Do something else -->

    </oherwise>
</choice>
```

Or you can use an expression filter if you just want to drop the message if not OPTIONS:

```
<expression-filter
expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.method'] != 'OPTIONS']" />
```

More info on routing and filtering here:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Filters

Comment: i like the idea of using the choice router to have the option to do something there. terrific, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is, you can use `message-filter` with `not-filter` and `message-property-filter` and return `405 method not allowed` on an HTTP OPTIONS request is unaccepted by the filter.

Below is a sample flow

```
<flow name="filterOptionsMethod">
    <http:listener config-ref="httpListener" path="/test" doc:name="receiveReq" />
    <message-filter onUnaccepted="set405" doc:name="filterOptionsMethod">
        <not-filter>
            <message-property-filter pattern="http.method=options" caseSensitive="false" scope="inbound" />
        </not-filter>
    </message-filter>
</flow>
```

and `onUnaccepted`

```
<sub-flow name="set405">
    <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="405" doc:name="405" />
    <set-payload value="HTTP method OPTIONS not allowed" doc:name="setRes" />
</sub-flow>
```